# Modify this loop to fit my jQuery slider (slides)

Tags: jquery, loop, slideshow

I´m trying to make a slider which takes thumbnails from a certain custom post type and displays for of them for each "slide". I get the slider and thumbnails to work like they should, but I´m unsure of how I should modify the loop to get it to display 4 posts in a container, then repeat with the next 4 posts and so on.

My loop looks like this:

```
<div id="slides">
    <div class="slides_container">

        <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'fastighet', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'ASC')); ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="slide">
                <?php $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, "url", true);
                if($url!='') {
                    echo '<a href="'.$url.'">';
                    echo the_post_thumbnail('admin-list-thumb');
                    echo '</a>';
                } else {
                    echo the_post_thumbnail('admin-list-thumb');
                } ?>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </div> <!-- end .slides_container -->

    <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">next</a>

</div> <!-- end .slides -->
```

Every div with the class of slide becomes a slide as you can see. But how can I make it put 4 posts into each such slide, then 4 post more into another slide etc.

Any help or tips would be really appreciated!

Comment: Since you already know how to query your posts, and how to return the featured image from those posts, what's left is really a **PHP** question, rather than a **WordPress** question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried very simple math. `<div class="slide">` will print after every 4 post. So, if statement with old school logic `$i%4 == 0`

```
<div class="slides_container">

                        <?php 
                            $args = array(
                                                        'post_type' => 'fastighet',
                                                        'numberposts' => -1,
                                                        'orderby' => 'ASC'
                                                    );
                            $posts = get_posts($args);
                            ?>
                        <?php $i = 0; foreach($posts as $post): ?>
                            <?php if($i%4 == 0): ?>
                                <div class="slide">
                            <?php endif; 
                                        $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, "url", true);
                                        if($url) {
                                                echo '<a href="'.$url.'">';
                                                echo the_post_thumbnail('admin-list-thumb');
                                                echo '</a>';
                                        } else {
                                                echo the_post_thumbnail('admin-list-thumb');
                                        } ?>
                                        <div class="caption">
                                                <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                                        </div>
                              <?php if($i%4 == 3): ?></div> <!--end .slide--><?php endif; ?> 

                        <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>

                </div> <!-- end .slides_container -->
```

Let me know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Seems I still only get one picture per slide for some reason. Also the thumbnails doesn´t link to anything, although they should link to each post.

Comment: @JohanDahl: there was a error on my code. Fixed it. Try now.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the missing <?php, and added it. Still nothing changed though. Still only get one slide per image :/

Comment: @JohanDahl Like what now?

Comment: I updated my code so some other stuff would work. Still only getting one post thumbnail per slide though.

http://pastebin.com/WbERsyUH

Comment: try echo `$i` to see if the value incrementing. How many results you get? You have couple of posts to show right?

Comment: @Sisir: I dont know how to do that. What should I type in more exactly?

There is probably something wrong in the code, it doesnt generate the divs as it should. Take a look at this: http://i.imgur.com/avdcs.png

Comment: add `echo 'Value of $i: '.$i` before `$i++` you should see incremental value of `$i`. And try disabling the javascript and see if javascript modifying the div.

Comment: Where should I echo this out? Inside the loop somewhere? If I echo that value out before the endwhile I get: Value of $i: 0 Value of $i: 1 Value of $i: 2

The slideshow works as intended if I replace the wordpress loop part with just static html. This makes me belive its still a loop problem somehow.

Comment: `$i` incrementing okey. I have changed the code. Used `get_posts()` now. Check if we have any luck this time :) Also if its not works come to chat "Stoppress" http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/stoppress

Comment: Seems I can´t type anything in the chat. Need 20 in reputation. Some day! :D Is there another way I can messege you on this site? I cant´t find any.

Comment: now you can! ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2717/discussion-between-sisir-and-johan-dahl)

Comment: The problem with the code seems to be that instead of putting 4 items in a slide, then create a new slide etc...the code makes every fourth item end up in a slide.

Comment: @johanDahl: please try now.

Comment: Your current code, with some slight adjustements, gave me just what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Almost correct. 
The only problem was that you actually don't want to print both the start and end on the same index. The following code works for me in a similar situation. The only real change is that $i starts at 1 and it print's the slides opening and closing tags on different counts.

Also took the liberty of cleaning up the code a bit.

```
<div id="slides">
    <div class="slides_container">

        <?php 
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'fastighet', 
            'posts_per_page' => -1 
        ) ); 
        $i = 1; 
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
            $loop->the_post(); 
            if( $i % 4 == 1 ) : 
                ?>
                <div class="slide">
                <?php 
            endif; 
            ?>
            <div class="fastighet-slider-entry">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end .fastighet-slider-entry -->
            <?php 
            if( $i % 4 == 0 ) : 
                ?>
                </div>
                <?php 
            endif; 
            ++$i; 
        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_query(); 
        ?>

    </div> <!-- end .slides_container -->

    <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">next</a>

</div> <!-- end .slides -->
```